# Swift for-in loop error as type String doesn't conform to protocol IntervalType

Tags: swift

I am working on a Swift iOS application. I am getting the compile error in for-in loop. Please check the code below, not sure why is this error throwing here?

```
var listDict : Dictionary = ["Insurance":"home", "Saving":"MutualFund"]
for valueName in listDict {

    switch valueName {

        case "Insurance":
            println("My insurance mname")
        default:
            println("Defualt")
    }        
}
```

and compile error I got is,

```
Type String doesn't conform to protocol IntervalType
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var listDict : Dictionary = ["Insurance":"home", "Saving":"MutualFund"]
for valueName in listDict.keys {

    switch valueName {

    case "Insurance":
       println("My insurance mname")
    default:
       println("Defualt")
   }

}
```

Here you will traverse through  all keys of your dictionary, which you intend to do according to your `case` statement.

in your code, you're trying to traverse key:value pairs. I suspect, error arise once compiler reaches `case` - it is trying to compare String to Tuple, which is not known how to do.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and answer

Answer (score 1):

`valueName` is a tuple, you therefore need to access one of its elements - either the key or value in this case. Taking your example:

```
for valueName in listDict {
    switch valueName.0 {
    case "Insurance":
        print("Value = \(valueName.1)")
    default:
        print("Defualt")
    } 
}
```

Or, which I personally think is more readable:

```
for (key, value) in listDict {
    switch key {
        case "Insurance":
            println("Value = \(value)")
        default:
            println("Default")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and answer

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out already, the structure you should expect is a tuple.

You can easily check what is the type of a variable (if not explicitly stated) by clicking on the "Quick help" in your Xcode project.

[image]

As you can see the type of `valueName` is `(String, String)`.

Comment: When i clicked quick help, it showed me only one string,  let valueName :String

Comment: Your cursor in the code editor must be on the same location where the variable is used.